# Trying to retrieve Firestore data using RXJS and Signals without Observables in Angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable, signals

I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve data from Firestore using RXJS and Signals. However, I want to avoid using Observables in this particular scenario. I have the following code, which uses Observables to fetch the user's profile and posts from Firestore based on a user ID:

My code:

```
profile_user_uid = signal<string | null>(null);

profile = toSignal(
  toObservable(this.profile_user_uid).pipe(
    switchMap((uid) => {
      if (uid) {
        const user_profile = docData<_User>(
          doc(this.firestore, 'users', uid) as DocumentReference<_User>,
          {
            idField: 'uid',
          }
        );
        const user_posts = collectionData<Post>(
          query<Post>(
            collection(
              this.firestore,
              'users',
              uid,
              'posts'
            ) as CollectionReference<Post>,
            orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ),
          {
            idField: 'id',
          }
        );
        return of({
          user_profile,
          user_posts,
        });
      } else {
        return of({
          user_profile: null,
          user_posts: null,
        });
      }
    })
  )
);
```

Is it possible to modify this code to achieve the same result without getting Observables? I want to explore alternative solutions that utilize Signals or other methods available in RXJS. Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "alternative solutions that utilize Signals or other methods available in RXJS". Signals have nothing to do with RxJS. Signals are part of Angular. While Observables and Signals have a small overlap on the end goal, they're very different by nature. Observables will let you manipulate streams of data exactly how you want to. And by stream of data, I mean data changes over time. Signals are not here for that. If you embrace RxJS for asynchronous code you'll make your life easier, not harder IMO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get Firebase version 9 Firestore data as a Signal in Angular version 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383716/trying-to-get-firebase-version-9-firestore-data-as-a-signal-in-angular-version-1)