# Trying to get Firebase version 9 Firestore data as a Signal in Angular version 16

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable, signals

I'm currently working on an Angular 16 project and using Firebase version 9 for my backend. I'm trying to retrieve data from Firestore and have it returned as an Observable stream in the form of a Signal. However, I'm facing some difficulties with the implementation.

Here's what I have so far:

```
  profile_user_uid = signal<string | null>(null); // getting the ID as a signal

  profile_user$ = toSignal( // trying to convert back to signal
    toObservable(this.profile_user_uid).pipe(
      tap((uid) => console.log('uid', uid)), // this shows the UID
      map((uid) => {
        if (uid) {
          const user = docData<_User>(
            doc(this.firestore, 'users', uid) as DocumentReference<_User>,
            {
              idField: 'uid',
            }
          );
          console.log('user', user); // user Observable {source: Observable, operator: ƒ}
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    )
  );
```

HTML template:

```
<!-- async pipe included to show data else it will be as [Object Object] which is not the result wanted since the plan to convert it to signal is to avoid using async pipe -->    
{{ profile_service.profile_user$() | async | json }}
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to convert the Firestore snapshot into a Signal so that I can easily subscribe to it in my Angular components. I have been using Observables in my project, but I'm not sure how to handle Signals in this context.

Can someone guide me on how to properly retrieve Firestore data as a Signal in Angular 16 using Firebase version 9? Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

In Angular 16 and Firebase version 9, Signals are not natively supported. However, you can achieve similar functionality using Observables.

In your HTML template, you can use the async pipe to subscribe to the observable and display the data:

By using Observables and leveraging the async pipe in Angular, you can achieve a similar behavior to Signals and simplify the subscription and rendering of Firestore data in your components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).